# Testing Application Helper that Depends on Controller

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd, integration-tests, bdd

I am working on practicing TDD/BDD/ATDD and I am working on a `rails` application.

I created a helper method that depends conditionally on the type of controller being tested.

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def devise_add_flash
    if controller.devise_controller?
      flash.now[:error] = flash[:error] + resource.errors.full_messages
    end
  end
end
```

Is unit testing this a bad idea? Should I be testing the "end behaviour" of this method (e.g. checking the flashes appear at the controller/view level) since that is really the "API" I care about maintaining, not the implementation of flash, etc.?

Am I approaching this the correct way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24919976/rspec-3-how-to-test-flash-messages  has info to test flash messages.

Comment: The question is conflating so many different approaches it is unclear and overly broad.

Answer (score -2):

Adam,
It clearly depends on your test strategy.
In that case I guess I’d rather unit test it since this is a global behavior. 
Regards,
Benoit